# How to add Java doc link in Eclipse for selenium 3.141.59

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium

I have added selenium 3.141.59 to my project in Eclipse IDE. There are 7 jar files in selenium's latest release.
I tried to add Javadoc link - https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/overview-summary.html in each jar file of selenium. But the Eclipse editor is not showing any documentation when hover over the selenium method.
Can anyone please help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You are entering the incorrect javadoc URL, you need to add below url:** https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/

**Please follow the below steps to configure the Javadocs with selenium jar:**

**Complete steps:**

**1).  Open the Build Path page of the project (right-click, properties, Java build path).**

[image]

**2) Libraries tab will get opened then expand the selenium and select the javadoc location and click on edit.**

[image]

**3) Enter the location to the file which contains the Javadoc. for Selenium use the link - https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/ and then press okay.**

[image]

**4) Now you can see the documentation:**

[image]

Comment: @NurulHasan : Sure, But please accept the answer, if I am able to solve your problem.

Comment: @ Abhishek Dhoundiyal, thank you for giving a 100% working solution. Now eclipse shows documentation for each keyword.

Comment: @NurulHasan: Gentle reminder, plz help the community by marking the answer.